# How to change color of a button component of an ionic app in appery

Tags: css, button, ionic-framework, appery.io

I am a newbie in Appery. Can some one tell me the steps to set custom color for a Button component using CSS.

Comment: http://blog.bismallion.com/apperyio-tutorial-how-to-change-components-css-style/

Comment: @Edison This is not a proper way , i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all Appery Buttons are set by CSS, so you have three options

1. you can choose one of the drop downs when you select the button called Swatch by picking a letter you can select the precoded colors from the drop down based on the theme you are using.
2. you can create a new css sub sheet and just assign a specific value a color or a specific group of items (all buttons) a color
3. (I WOULD NOT ADVISE THIS) you can edit the general css sheet for the theme.

Comment: Thanks, I tried creating css sub sheet and set class for the component and it worked.